# How to make text bold in JSON and bind it to Windows Phone

Tags: json, windows-phone-8

I have following JSON file which I am binding to Windows Phone textblock

```
{"Groups":[
  {
    "UniqueId": "Cat-1",
    "Title": "Inspirational",
    "ImagePath": "Assets/DarkGray.png",
    "Items":
    [
      {
        "UniqueId": "11",
        "Title": "Item Title: 1",
        "ImagePath": "Assets/LightGray.png",
        "Description" : "The best and most beautiful things in the world...",
        "Content" : "The best and most beautiful things in the world",
        "Author" : "Helen Keller"
      }
    ]
  }
]
}
```

Above file content data is getting binded to textblock

```
<Grid Grid.Row="1" x:Name="ContentRoot" Margin="19,9.5,19,0">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Content}" Style="{ThemeResource BaseTextBlockStyle}" Margin="0,-6.5,0,26.5" CharacterSpacing="{ThemeResource PivotHeaderItemCharacterSpacing}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Author}" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,10,369" Height="56" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"></TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

I want part of CONTENT in JSON file to BOLD / UNDERLINE.

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Have you tried styling the relevant `TextBlock`? Is there an issue with that? Or are you trying to style a portion of the bound text?

Answer (score 0):

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding your_binding}" FontWeight="Bold" TextDecorations="Underline"></TextBlock>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you only want a part of the content bold use RichTextBox.

```
<RichTextBox>
    <Paragraph>
        <Run Text="{Binding notBold}"></Run>
        <Run Text="{Binding bold}" FontWeight="Bold"></Run>
    </Paragraph>
</RichTextBox>
```

You can either edit your json structure or parse it and assign to proper objects in your logic.